# How to call defined function using Parameter passed from CMD in python

Tags: python

My code is given below

```
def sum():
   print "sum"
def div():
   print "div"

test = sys.argv[1]
```

On terminal I am passing `Python script.py sum`.

Here `sum` is a parameter i.e `sys.argv[1]` .

It should print sum but nothing gets printed .Anyone know how to do it or what problem is there ?

Comment: Why do you think this should print anything? Where do you call either `sum` or `div`?

Comment: i am calling sum by passing argument which will store in test @DanielRoseman

Comment: No, you're not.

Comment: Do you know how to pass it ? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman for your response but i got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be something like this. Note that this assigns the function definition to a variable and then executes is.

```
import sys

def sum():
   print "sum"
def div():
   print "div"

test = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], sys.argv[1])
test()
```

Usage:

```
~> python my_script_name.py sum
```

Comment: It is giving                                                                                                 
 Error   test = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], sys.argv[1])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sum()'

Comment: Remove the brackets `()`, check the usage section I added @sachindubey